# Shiny Dashboard to show right plot according to user input via radioButton

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, radio-button, shinydashboard

It is my first time asking here. I will try to be as concise as possible but also providing the needed information.

I am building a dashboard using shinydashboard, and one of the things I want the dashboard to show is the following:

A user clicks on a radioButton (with 10 options located on the sidebar), then what I want is to show the plot corresponding to that clicked radio button on the dashboard body. This means that if the user clicks a different button, a different plot (possibly from a different data set) is drawn. Here it is the code with bogus variables/data:

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Data", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    radioButtons(inputId = "Partner", label = "Choose a Partner:", selected = "A",
                 choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
                            )
               )
            )
)
```

This is the relevant part of the body piece:

```
tabBox(title = "Partnerships", width = 6,
       tabPanel("Parner A", plotOutput("partnerA")))
```

And this is just a snipet on the server piece:

```
Partner <- reactive({
      filter (data, partner == input$Partner)
    })
    output$partnerA <- renderPlot({
         p <-
            bphc_bsa %>% 
            filter(partner == "A") %>%
            ggplot(aes(x=Grade, fill = Grade)) +
            geom_bar()
```

I got the plot and right radiobuttons on the sidebar, but clicking the button does not affect the output. 
I really appreciate any help as I am completely new to this.

Comment: Remove the `Partner <- reactive...` part. Just change inside your `renderPlot`... `filter(partner == "A")` to `filter(partner == input$Partner)` and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you, man! It just worked :)